# how to clean up data in R

Tags: r, excel, screen-scraping

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GWCSO.png)I'm helping out my professor by automating one of his work. He has a word document that contains information of students in tabular form and there are many tables in each document (sometimes in the hundreds). I've created the function below in R to extract data from Word

```r
library(xml2)
get_tbls <- function(word_doc) {
  tmpd <- tempdir()
  tmpf <- tempfile(tmpdir=tmpd, fileext=".zip")
  
  file.copy(word_doc, tmpf)
  unzip(tmpf, exdir=sprintf("%s/docdata", tmpd))
  
  doc <- read_xml(sprintf("%s/docdata/word/document.xml", tmpd))
  
  unlink(tmpf)
  unlink(sprintf("%s/docdata", tmpd), recursive=TRUE)
  
  ns <- xml_ns(doc)
  
  tbls <- xml_find_all(doc, ".//w:tbl", ns=ns)
  
  lapply(tbls, function(tbl) {
    
    cells <- xml_find_all(tbl, "./w:tr/w:tc", ns=ns)
    rows <- xml_find_all(tbl, "./w:tr", ns=ns)
    dat <- data.frame(matrix(xml_text(cells), 
                             ncol=(length(cells)/length(rows)), 
                             byrow=TRUE), 
                      stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
    colnames(dat) <- dat[1,]
    dat <- dat[-1,]
    rownames(dat) <- NULL
    dat
    
  })
  
}
```

this function extracts data from word document and after that, I've used writexl package to export the data to excel but it is also displaying stuff i don't need.

[image]

Comment: Without an example document, and some idea of what you want the output to contain, I doubt we will be able to help much.

Comment: sure let me attach the original document, your help will be much appreciated.

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/EfbhvAe.png    (there are hundreds of such tables in the document)

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear what you need but I would probably use dplyr to clean the data frame.

Using your data frame dat:

```
dat <- dat %>%
select(c(text, level))%>%
filter(text!="")%>%
filter(level!="")
```

or

```
dat <- dat %>%
select(-c(doc_index, content_type, is_header))
```

Comment: Please specify all non-base packages with `library()`.